# Get IDs that appear one than once in the month

Tags: postgresql

I need to create a query that select the "employee_id, project_id ,start_date and end_date when  [for a employee_id has more than one project_id  in the same month.]
The think is that i don't know how to see if for a employee_id has more than one project_id  in the same month. I know one way is to use  between '2010-01-01' and '2010-02-01' but this is not the right one , cause i don't know in which date will begin or so.So it needs to be dinamic.
[image]

```
Employee_id Project_id  Project_ Employee_id    Start_date  End_date    occupied    status  Role_id key

"47"    "96"    "1440"  "2019-04-07"    "2019-04-30"    100 "ON_PROJECT"    "3" "NO"
"47"    "96"    "1441"  "2019-04-05"    "2019-04-20"    100 "ON_PROJECT"    "250"   "NO"
"47"    "131"   "1442"  "2019-04-07"    "2019-04-15"    100 "ON_PROJECT"    "3" "NO"
```

I need those, when the Start_date End_date is in the same month and for ex.. for the same Employee_id and Project_id where the Start_date ,End_date are in the same month .
I need the result to be like this example
ex
(47,96,1440,'2019-04-07','2019-04-30'), (47,96,1441,'2019-04-06','2019-04-20'),   just for a month , i know there are many lines 
that maybe is the same result but i need to work only for one , it will not have more than 2 Employee_id and  Project_id  for the same month.

Comment: Please put your sample data as text. So it can be copied for test purposes. Please add your expected output as well

Comment: Will Start_date and End_date always be within the same month and year?

Comment: @lau that's what i need, when the Start_date End_date  is in the same month and for ex.. for the same Employee_id   and  Project_id   where the Start_date ,End_date   are in the same month so i get them both

Comment: What about the other 47,96 rows? Why is there no 47,131 result which also appear in one month?

Comment: That will be also 131 but i just show you one part , cause if it works for one it works for all

Comment: Sry, I did't really get what you expected output should be. Please by so kind to add the WHOLE expected output. As I understand now you want to get ALL rows because it's always the same employee whose projects all exist in the same month...

Comment: Sure i will do it now

Comment: Maybe another data set would help with different persons, projects and time ranges...

Comment: Where comes 41,35 from? Your expected output does not fit to your input data anymore.

Comment: I miswrote them but i edit now i think now is ook

Comment: ok, and now: Why don't you expect the last row? It is still the same employee, project_id in the same month as the first both?

Comment: I edit the question, try working with this 3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187323/discussion-between-ilia-tapia-and-s-man).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=3e601b296f63c675629e3eb719014bfa)

(Not that for some more tests, I changed the row `1439` `end_date` to few months later and the `project_id` to `132` and added a last row with `employee_id = 48` which should not be shown)

```
SELECT
   employee_id,
   project_id,
   MIN(start_date),
   MAX(end_date)
FROM
   emp, generate_series(date_trunc('month', start_date), date_trunc('month', end_date) , interval '1 month') gs
GROUP BY employee_id, project_id
HAVING COUNT(gs) >= 2
```

1. `date_trunc` takes the first of the month. It's a kind of normalization because I am only interested in months not in the actual days.
2. `generate_series` generates rows for every month the project entry exist. (See project `132`, which appears in three months from april to june.). This expanding allows to group by project/employee and count the different months
3. `GROUP` the `employee_id` and `project_ids` groups and count the months they appear.
4. Groups with more than one month are filtered with `HAVING` clause.

---

After some changes of the requirements:

Using the [window function `COUNT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/tutorial-window.html) allows to count the rows of a certain group without any need of aggregating. So `COUNT(*) OVER()` adds the count of the group as new column and this can be filtered afterwards.

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=f8533916af784059e358d8dfc7ab1f2b)

If `start_date` and `end_date` are in the same month:

```
SELECT 
    employee_id,
    project_id,
    start_date,
    end_date
FROM (
    SELECT
        *,
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY employee_id, project_id, date_trunc('month', start_date))
    FROM
       emp_same
) s
WHERE count >= 2
```

If not you'll have to expand all months where a project appears (as described above):

```
SELECT 
    employee_id,
    project_id,
    start_date,
    end_date
FROM (
    SELECT
        *,
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY employee_id, project_id, gs)
    FROM
       emp_diff, generate_series(date_trunc('month', start_date), date_trunc('month', end_date) , interval '1 month') gs
) s
WHERE count >= 2
```

Comment: (47,96,1440,'2019-04-07','2019-04-30'),
(47,96,1441,'2019-04-06','2019-04-20'),    i need to get this result,
as i said for employee_id=47 that has the same project_id=96 and they are at the same month @S-Man

Comment: First: Please add the expected result to your question. Second: Explain why do you expect this: In your example 47,131 appears also several times in this month

Comment: i get from your query  
47 96 2019-04-06 2019-04-30 ::::::
47 131 2019-04-07 2019-04-30  ::::::
47 132 2019-04-05 2019-06-30   ::::::

Comment: Yeah even for the 131 if this is show for the employee_id=47 in the same one sure is ok to get it

Comment: Yes sure I am trying. But really, I still don't understand your expected result. You should really expand your explanation...

Comment: i just edit try to use only those date and the result is as i told you

Comment: the result will be 
(47,96,1440,'2019-04-07','2019-04-30'),
(47,96,1441,'2019-04-06','2019-04-20'),

Comment: you're welcome. For future please consider that we need a MINIMIZED sample data which shows in a compact ways ALL your use case and a COMPLETE output set. That would save a lot of time and maybe changes the query completely.